# Cannot find the pages document library in my SharePoint 2013 site?

Tags: 2013, pages

I cannot find the document library pages in my sharepoint 2013 site. Do I need to activate some feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Enabling **publishing feature** in your site collection and check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Enabling publishing feature at the site collection level is not enough, you need to enable publishing feature at site level also to see Pages library (Manage site features)